# Get post code from getlinkinfo

Tags: here-api

Is there a way to get the post code as part of the address returned by the getlinkinfo resource of the routing API? Example:- http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&waypoint=50.05564304861044,8.38889128575724&linkattributes=all returns street, city, country but not postcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the HERE Geocoder API and do a reverse geocode for the position. This will get you the postal code among other location information and link attributes (locationattributes=linkInfo). The last option is new since this week. Let me know if this helps or what exactly you are trying to do and what response details you need.
Following is an example call:
http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=8&maxresults=1&mode=retrieveAddresses&prox=50.05564304861044%2C8.38889128575724%2C250&locationattributes=linkInfo